# Why won't my water heater light after a basement flood?

Tags: water-heater, flooding

Last night my basement flooded about 8 inches and got into my gas water heater. It was propped up on bricks but about 1-2 inches of water hit the very bottom of the heater and got the insulation wet at the bottom about 1-2 inches. The pilot light will not light.

I put a fan near it and plan on taking the pilot light and burner out to dry it but was wondering If I can cut of the 2 inches of insulation? Or should I dry it?

Comment: Are you talking about an external insulation wrap? Did it flood to the point of submerging the burner assembly?

Answer (score 2):

A few hours with a fan isn't enough to properly dry out a flooded appliance. In fact, you risk causing further permanent damage by running electronics that are still wet.

Run the fan (and lower the room humidity) for at least a few *days*. Keep power disconnected until then. Open the cabinet as much as possible by removing cover panels, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that I've never dealt with a flooded appliance professionally, so the following is just what I'd try personally. Does your water heater have a push-button piezo sparker for lighting? Do you see it sparking? I wonder if there could be residual moisture or residue that "shorts out" the high-voltage piezo impulse and causes it not to spark. It sounds like your burner got wet but the gas valve remained dry.

Most of the push-button ignited water heaters I've seen could also be lit by conventional means: a long match or a long butane gas fire starter. I'd try lighting with one of these methods and see how that goes.